# Searching in GridView column with relation in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a model with foreign key `city_id` that references table `Cities (id)`. In the `GridView` I show city title instead of id, and I know how to add searching for column with foreign key, i.e, in view:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
       //some columns
        [ 
            'attribute' => 'city_id',
            'value'=>'city.title
        ],
]);
```

And in search model (`search()` function) I add:

```
$query->joinWith('city');
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'cities.title', $this->city_id]);
```

And it works fine. But I also want to show `region` in my grid, and my table `Cities` has a foreign key `region_id` which references `Regions(id)`.
I added the region title to the grid:

```
 GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
       //some columns
        [ 
            'attribute' => 'city_id',
            'value'=>'city.title
        ],
        'city.region.title_en',
]);
```

Now I dont know how to add searching and how to change `search()` function, because I dont have `region_id` in my main model, I retrieve it through `city`.
I would appreciate any advise.

Comment: `$query->joinWith(['city','city.region']);`, and make relation `getRegion()` in your city model. If that wont help - define relation `getRegion` in your `GridView` model with `via` cities.

Comment: ok but what will be the 'attribute' in grid?

Comment: @GyuzalR.  You can declare `public` variable.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505137/how-to-connect-3-tables-in-yii2-and-display-in-gridview-then-make-sorting-work-c

Comment: it seems to be unsolved and the author says the textbox did not appear. I did the same and textbox is also missing. Could you please provide some code.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not forget to add `region_id` to your search model.